# Issue while launching project in device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I am facing a weird issue while running my project on the device. I see below error even though the app file is present in the mentioned path. Also the project gets copied in the device & I need to tap on app icon to launch it but it fails while launching from XCODe. Any clue - is this because of spaces in my schema name?:

```
error: failed to launch '/Users/abhi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-atlkwwnwccqaopgembmyzeecthfx/Build/Products/QA - Debug - Production-iphoneos/MyProject.app/MyProject' -- No such file or directory (/Users/abhi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-atlkwwnwccqaopgembmyzeecthfx/Build/Products/QA - Debug - Production-iphoneos/MyProject.app/MyProject)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Delete app from your device, switch `OFF` and `ON` your device, clean your code and then run it on device, it will install..

If not Restart your Xcode...

I have tried this when i have faced same problem and this one worked for me

Comment: I thought so & tried this 3 times... Same error all the times :-(!

Comment: What finally worked for me was to turn the `device` off then on. Nothing else worked.

Answer (score 0):

Tried advice by Sree Charan with no success for XCode 4.3.3.  Ultimately (and I'm not sure this is what fixed it), I went to Validate Settings on the Editor Menu and it updated settings from GDB to LLDB and then it worked.

I'm only providing the info above in hopes it might help someone else.  I have no way to verify that is what fixed this problem (and I spent 2 hours looking for a solution).